# MYSQL INSERT INTO existing table data FROM 2 separate tables ON id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

I have a table 'new_foobar' that is empty. it has columns 'fbc_primary_key', 'fbc_two', fbc_three, and fbc_four.

fbc_three defaults to 'apple'

then I have a table 'foo', with a columns 'fc_pimary_key', 'fc_two'. And a table 'bar' with columns 'bc_primary_key', 'bc_two', 'bc_three'.

fbc_primary_key, bc_primary_key, and fc_primary_key, are all primary keys of their respective tables.

how does one insert fc_two, into fbc_two, and bc_three into fbc_four.

```
TABLE foo
fc_primary_key | fc_two |
-------------------------
1              | hello  |
2              | goodbye|

TABLE bar
bc_primary_key | bc_two | bc_three |
------------------------------------
1              | abc    | 123      |
2              | def    | 456      |

*NOTE bar and foo have a 1-to-1 relationship.


TABLE foobar
fbc_primary_key | fbc_two | fbc_three | fbc_four |
---------------------------------------
/* empty */

...AFTER SOME SQL MAGIC....

TABLE foobar
fbc_primary_key | fbc_two | fbc_three | fbc_four |
---------------------------------------------------
1               | hello   | apple     | 123      |
2               | goodbye | apple     | 456      |
```

The problem I am having with is, how to get the columns of data to fall under the foobar column.

Comment: Is there always a corresponding entry in `bar` for each entry in `foo` (and vice versa)?

Comment: bar and foo have a 1-to-1 relationship.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into foobar
select 
  ifnull(f.fbc_primary_key, b.fbc_primary_key), 
  fbc_two, 
  fbc.three
from 
  foo f
  full outer join bar b on b.fbc_primary_key  = f.fbc_primary_key
```

If you only want records that exist in both tables, you can use inner join. You can skip the ifnull too, because both f and b will have an id.

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship between `foo` and `bar` is one-to-one and required on both sides:

```
INSERT INTO foobar (
  SELECT f.fc_primary_key, f.fc_two, b.bc_three 
  FROM foo f INNER JOIN bar b ON f.fc_primary_key = b.bc_primary_key);
```

Comment: @Golez's answer is better for the generic case.